# How do you set a string data member from a base class, with a derived classed?

Tags: c++, class, abstract, protected, derived

I have figured out most of the code/assignment, here is part of the "To-Do" I can't figure out:

- The derived classes set the m_type, but note, there is no setType function to do 
  so (and you can't add one).

Here is my code (nothing in main can be changed):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
const double PI = 3.14159265359;

class Geometry
 {
 public:
     Geometry(std::string name)
        :m_name(name)
    {

    }
    virtual double computeVolume() = 0;
    virtual double computeSurfaceArea() = 0;

    std::string getName() { return m_name; }
    std::string getType() { return m_type; }

protected:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_type;

 };

class Box : public Geometry
{
 public:

    Box(std::string name, double length, double width, double height)
        : Geometry(name), m_length(length), m_width(width), m_height(height)
    { 

    }

    virtual double computeSurfaceArea()
    {
        return (2 * (m_height * m_width)) + (2 * (m_height * m_length)) + (2 
        * (m_length * m_width));
    }

     virtual double computeVolume()
    {
        return m_length * m_width * m_height;
    }
 protected:
     double m_length;
     double m_width;
     double m_height;
};

class Sphere : public Geometry
{
public:
    Sphere(std::string name, double radius)
        :Geometry(name), m_radius(radius)
    {

    }

    virtual double computeVolume()
    {
        return  (4.0/3.0) * PI * (m_radius * m_radius * m_radius);
    }

    virtual double computeSurfaceArea()
    {
        return 4 * PI * (m_radius * m_radius);
    }

 protected:
     double m_radius;

 };

void report(Geometry* obj)
{

     std::cout << "----- Geometry Report -----" << std::endl << std::endl
        << "Type: " << obj->getType() << std::endl
        << "Name: " << obj->getName() << std::endl
        << "Volume " << obj->computeVolume() << std::endl
        << "Surface Area " << obj->computeSurfaceArea() << std::endl << 
std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Geometry*> items;

    items.push_back(new Box("Box 1", 1, 2, 3));
    items.push_back(new Box("Box 2", 2, 3, 4));
    items.push_back(new Sphere("Sphere 1", 5));
    items.push_back(new Sphere("Sphere 2", 6));

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        report(items[i]);
    } 

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly then you just need to set the `m_type` variable directly within the constructor of each of your derived classes. You are able to do this because this variable has `protected` access which means derived classes can manipulate it directly. So you should simply be able to do:

```
Box(std::string name, double length, double width, double height)
    : Geometry(name), m_length(length), m_width(width), m_height(height)
{ 
   m_type = "Box type";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A protected member variable or function is very similar to a private member but it provided one additional benefit that they can be accessed in child classes which are called derived classes.

So you can directly set m_type from derived class.

Example::

```
class Box {
          protected:
               double width;
          };

     class SmallBox:Box { // SmallBox is the derived class.
          public:
   void setSmallWidth( double wid );
   double getSmallWidth( void );
   };

    // Member functions of child class
          double SmallBox::getSmallWidth(void) {
        return width ;
       }

 void SmallBox::setSmallWidth( double wid ) {
     width = wid;
  }

     // Main function for the program
     int main() {
         SmallBox box;

     // set box width using member function
         box.setSmallWidth(5.0);
         cout << "Width of box : "<< box.getSmallWidth() << endl;

            return 0;
        }
```

In your case It may be used like this

```
 Box(std::string name, double length, double width, double height)
    : Geometry(name), m_length(length), m_width(width), m_height(height)
{ 
   m_type="abc";
}
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be easy! thanks for the help!